# How do you keep appsettings.development.json private on a shared feature branch

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc

By requirement I have to share a feature branch with other users and they keep changing their appsettings.development.json db connection string and pushing that change to the feature branch and it's causing frustration and confusing.  Is there a way to mitigate this issue?

Comment: I usually add a new file and call it `appsettings.local.json` with `builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.local.json", true);`, exclude it from git by adding an entry to `.gitignore`and make it optional.

Comment: To add to @DavidG's suggestion, if you go his way, *please* include all parameters supported with default values in one of the other configurations files **or** keep an up to date documentation of the possible key:values. Far too often I saw projects where it was expected that the new team-members create those local files, and had to copy it from others because no documentation / examples were available.